# onCreate is called twice

Tags: android, countdowntimer, oncreate, screen-rotation

I have 2 activities - MainActivity and page1. I have intent from the first like this:

```
 button_forward.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true ;
            }
```

However, my Page1 class's onCreate is called twice! i can detect it with toast message: it appears twice on the screen:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toast.makeText(Page1.this, "onCreate 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page1);
    //some code here like findview by id...
}
        });`
```

I do have some methods that use countdowntimer in my Page1 activity, timers that wait for 2 secs, i commented them out, but onCreate() still gets called twice.

I added code to prevent screen rotating, but the error persists

Comment: I think the problem is Toasting a message berore onCreate ...
so when execution of second activity start it will Toast the message.. but after that you are calling super.onCreate() .. So that may be possible reason that onCreate will call twice..\

Comment: @Moinkhan, but super.onCreate must be called in every method right? this is a rule to always call superclass method - super.onDestroy() etc

Comment: yeah right ..but it is good practice to write super() on first statement ...
Using super as first statement allow onCreate() to do it's default behavior ..then toast the message ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your touch listener doesn't check which type of event we have, this means that your `onTouch` should be called like 100 times per second, but it actually is called only twice because the new Activity UI covers the button. Use this code to check which event we have:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return false;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

If the action is `ACTION_DOWN` it means that the user has just touched the button. If it is `ACTION_UP` it means that the user lifted his / her finger.

Comment: beat me by seconds, if you need to intercept before the view processes it look for the down action

Comment: @Mateiaru, sorry i dont' get it: why should we return true if the action is not down?